# How to add an extension button to the url bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

is it possible to add the action button of an extension to the address bar in firefox?

[image]

Comment: Yes, [pageAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/pageAction).